# Return \' within a MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have data stored in MySQL that looks like this:

```
q1
People\'s
People\'s
People\'s
```

I'm trying to write a MySQL statement to return a count of these but it's causing me an issue, I have tried all the following but to no avail:

```
SELECT * AS Total,
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM results WHERE q1 = 'People\'s') AS Count_Q1
FROM results

SELECT * AS Total,
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM results WHERE q1 = 'People'\'s')
FROM results

SELECT * AS Total,
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM results WHERE q1 = 'People''\'s')
FROM results
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: "To no avail" meaning error? incorrect results?

Comment: Try `'People\\'s'` escaping the backslash.

Comment: Or perhaps `'People\''s'`?

Comment: The fact that you have `\'` in the database is the real issue.

Comment: ^^^ True. Using `REPLACE` would fix that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I agree, however, I need to overcome it without changing the data in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(q1) FROM results WHERE q1 = 'People\\\'s') AS Total
FROM results
```

The above is coming right from the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html):

[image]

This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47325/1/0) demonstration shows that it does work.

Comment: Hmm, this looked promising but it stops the query from running :-(

Comment: Must be something with my query then, as when I use that directly within MySQL it works a treat.

Comment: This should have worked. After seeing (*and giving it a 2nd thought*) what I posted ``'People\\'s'`` would have only escaped the backslash and not the apostrophe.

Comment: As explained, oddly it works when run within MySQL but not via my PHP page in a larger query - it has to be something to do with my query.  It's the right answer, even if it's not working (if that makes sense!).

Comment: You did have the alias for the total (`AS Total`) in the wrong spot.  I updated my answer to show how it should be.  Maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: @Homer_J In PHP backslahes and quotes must be escaped once again.

Answer (score 0):

> Select * as Total,(select count(q1) from results where q1 = 'People\\\'s') from results

it should work for u